# Photo Uploads to Firebase Database and Storage but doesn't save photo in application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

So I have an edit profile page where the user can change their profile picture and cover photo. I have it to where once the users selects their image, they click the saveButton and the photo is uploaded to Firebase Database and Firebase Storage and then the edit profile viewcontroller is dismissed and returns to profile view. Only problem I am having is that although the photo uploads to firebase, it doesn't save the image on the app if I close out and reopen it. I'm not sure what I am missing to make that happen. Here is the code below:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class NewEditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

    var ref = DatabaseReference.init()

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imagePicked = 0

    var selectedImage1: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        self.saveFIRData()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true


    }


    @IBAction func chooseImage1(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
            imagePicked = (sender as AnyObject).tag
            present(imagePicker, animated: true)
        }

        }

    @IBAction func chooseImage2(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
            imagePicked = (sender as AnyObject).tag
                present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
        let pickedImage2 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage

        if imagePicked == 1 {
            self.imageView1.image = pickedImage
        } else if imagePicked == 2 {
            self.imageView2.image = pickedImage2
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.saveFIRData()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    @objc func saveFIRData() {
        guard let image = imageView1.image else { return }

        self.uploadProfileImage(image){ url in

            self.saveProfileImage(profileURL: url!){ success in
                if success != nil{
                    print("yes")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension NewEditProfileViewController {


    func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?)->()) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users/\(uid)")
        let imageData = imageView1.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if error == nil{
                print("success")
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    completion(url)
                })
            }else{
                print("error in save image")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }


    func saveProfileImage(profileURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profilePhotoURL/\(uid)")
        let userObject = [
            "photoURL": profileURL.absoluteString
        ] as [String:Any]

        self.ref.child("users").child(uid).setValue(userObject)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code in function
`func saveProfileImage(profileURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ()))`
code to download image is missing you have to update your `saveProfileImage`to support download & then save to local app directory.

```
func saveProfileImage(profileURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let databaseRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users/profilePhotoURL/\(uid)")

    // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes), Change it according to your need
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
      if let error = error {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      } else {
        // Save `data` to your local directory here
        let imageFilename = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/" + "\(uid).jpg"
        data.write(toFile: imageFilename, atomically: true) 
      }
    }

    let userObject = [
        "photoURL": profileURL.absoluteString
    ] as [String:Any]

    self.ref.child("users").child(uid).setValue(userObject)
    }
}
```

Refer following sample code taken from Firebase guide [Download to local](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) section on file "Download File on iOS" page.

> ```
> // Create a reference to the file you want to download
> let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")
>
> // Create local filesystem URL
> let localURL = URL(string: "path/to/image")!
>
> // Download to the local filesystem
> let downloadTask = islandRef.write(toFile: localURL) { url, error in
>   if let error = error {
>     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
>   } else {
>     // Local file URL for "images/island.jpg" is returned
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi there! I have added you code that recommended but the only problem is that when I enter:  "databaseRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
      if let error = error { " I get an error that is saying "Value of type 'DatabaseReference' has no member 'getData'" any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @allenhinson214 use storage instance instead of database instance, i will update my answer

Comment: I changed it storage and now I'm getting an error on the line "data.write(toFile: imageFilename, atomically: true)" saying "Extra argument 'atomically' in call". Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Its not write function error check what arguments it expect and you are through.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have never used this part of code before so I'm not sure what would cause it to give me this error, so I'm still stuck on that error

Comment: I'm still stuck on what to do.

Comment: @allenhinson214 I have added sample code & documentation link for reference, This forum is to point out problem & guide you to right way, its not meant to provide entire solution. I hope you understand it.